# need help to subtract value radio buttons javascript code

Tags: javascript, radio-button, contact-form-7

how to subtract, two values from two sets of radio buttons.?

My radio buttons:

```
 <p>Baby Plan<br />
    [radio BPSUBPT id:BPSUBPT "Baby Plan $300.00 3 Sessions" "Baby Plan $500.00 4 Sessions"] </p>

<p>Did you have a Newborn session With ADP? <br />
[radio BUSPQ1 id:BUSPQ1 "Yes $150.00 off" "No $000.00"]
```

my java code that I have to calculate the total: ( but it adding it up I would like it to subtract to get the total.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var inputs = $('input[name="BPSUBPT"],  input[name="BUSPQ1"]');
        $(inputs).click(function() {
            var total = 0;
            $(inputs).filter(':checked').each(function() {
                var value = ($(this).val()).match(/\$([0-9]*)/)[1];
                total = total + parseInt(value);
            })
            $('#total').html('$' + total);
```

how do I get it to subtract to get a total.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1xwdBjH

Answer (score 0):

then subtract...

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var inputs = $('input[name="BPSUBPT"],  input[name="BUSPQ1"]');
        $(inputs).click(function() {
            var total = 0;
            $(inputs).filter(':checked').each(function() {
                var value = ($(this).val()).match(/\$([0-9]*)/)[1];
                total = total - parseInt(value);
            })
            $('#total').html('$' + total);
```

Comment: erikruina it still adding with a - sign in front

Comment: then its treating it as a string instead of number... try (parseInt(total) - parseInt(value))